# Importing the Groovy template engine into a Java project

Tags: java, groovy, template-engine

I would like to import the Groovy template engine in a standalone Java library. I got this idea after seeing that the Play Framework 1.2.4 also did it.

Is there a way to exclusively get the template engine without importing the whole Groovy framework?

Thanks

Comment: Probably not a direct answer to you but both Japid and Rythm template engine could be used independently, and they all provides similar usage experience with groovy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the new features in the Groovy 2.0 release is [modularization](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+2.0+modularization). There is a separate module for templating (everything in package `groovy.text`) e.g. `groovy-templates-2.0.0-rc-4.jar`. I am not quite sure what the dependencies of that module are so you might have to pull in some other Groovy modules. This will keep it to a minimum though. As 2.0 is not final yet you could probably try out a [RC version](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Download).

Answer (score 0):

Not to my knowledge, but you can run groovy code from a java class... see: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Embedding+Groovy

So you could get it to work with a bit of hacking.